# how do i include another commit from within the git pre-push hook?

Tags: git, bash, hook

I am trying to make an automated code change right before the push. I already have a `pre-push` script ready and working fine. It adds the changes and commits them.

However I have to send another push to include the commit, then cancel the original one. But `pre-push` only admits to stop the ongoing push with an error.

From within `pre-push`, how can i cancel the ongoing push without error?... or how can i add my changes to the ongoing push.

Thanks.

Comment: are you sure that pushing is the right place to convert the repo? Likely, you will make your repository users to feel some pain on every push, because they will have to rebase their changes after each push.

Comment: @user3159253 no need to rebase. as i said, it is working fine right now, it pushes the changes and all, but it finish with the error line.

Comment: @user3159253 No need to rebase since the new changes are already applied and committed. No pain to the users, aside from one second added delay while the new code is committed.